# Hyperlink on the baseline of a DIV

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="ui-accordion ui-widget" style="margin: 10px 0px 12px 0px;">
    <h3 class="ui-helper-reset ui-corner-top ui-accordion-header ui-state-default" 
        style="height: 24px; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 0px 0px 12px">Title</h3>
    <div class="ui-accordion-content-active ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom accordionContent" 
         style="height:150px; padding: 8px 12px;">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-image:url('/_assets/images/image1.png');">
               <%= Html.ActionLink("Link 1", "Index", "Home") %>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image:url(/_assets/images/image2.png);">
               <%= Html.ActionLink("Link 2", "Index", "Home") %>
            </li>
            <li style="background-image:url(/_assets/images/image3.png);">
               <%= Html.ActionLink("Link 3", "Index", "Appointment") %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

that render the following box on Chrome (without the red rectangle)

[image]

I would like to add an hyperlink just in the place of the red rectangle. How can I do it?

Please note that all the used styles are inline and the classes are all from jquery UI standard classes. I am not a designer and maybe this markup can be optimized. Any advice is welcomed... :)

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `div` inside the `<div class="ui-accordion ...>` with these styles:

```
position: absolute;
right: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
width: 5em;
height: 1.5em;
```

**[EDIT]** The parent `div` must have `position: relative` or it won't work (thanks to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51133/daniel))**[/EDIT]**

Note that you should give the box a definite size; you can't have it "grow" by itself. `width: 100%;` is ok, though.

Also note that this `div` doesn't extend the size of the parent `div`. If the accordion is too small, then the last entry will overlap with your link. The solution is to add an empty `div` with the necessary height to accordion to make room for the absolutely positioned one.

Comment: Make sure you set the parent div to position: relative!

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Without the Aaron suggestion the link was placed at the bottom of the page ;)